# Can't find PHP class after implementing namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I am dealing with an old PHP class called `Config` in a `Config.class.php` file.

Recently, I have implemented namespaces:

```
<?php

namespace Tfr\Partners\Smartfocus;

use Tfr\BaseApp;

class Config
{
    ...
    } else {
        $isProd = BaseApp::isProd();
    }
    ...
```

When I am running the code, I now get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tfr\BaseApp' not found in
<some_path>/Partners/Smartfocus/Config.class.php on line 45
```

but the `BaseClass` is there in a file called `<some_path>/BaseApp.class.php`. However, it does not have a namespace itself.

Unfortunately, it is used in many places in a large code base, and adding a namespace to `BaseClass` seems very risky.

How can I 'import' `BaseClass` in `Config` safely and get rid of my error?

Comment: Did you try `\BaseApp::isProd()`?

Comment: Can you not just load it using a simple `require_once()`?

Comment: @Charlotte I did, but I am getting an infinite loop leading to a segmentation fault. I am not sure this is related to namespaces and use. Do you think it is related?

Comment: Did you try composer dump-autoload